# How can I fix a hole (acid burn) in Vinyl floor (Bathroom)

Tags: repair, floor, vinyl

I'm seeking advice on repairing a small, circular hole in a semi-soft vinyl floor located in my bathroom. While the damage is noticeable, it's relatively shallow, measuring less than 1mm deep. I'm unsure whether I can simply fill it in (preferable if possible) or if a complete replacement is necessary.

Any insights or recommendations are greatly appreciated!

[image: floor close up]

[image: floor hole]

Comment: Do you have any sections of the flooring in a hidden spot?  Replacement of that small section is about the only repair that will look decent.

Comment: Vinyl tile, or vinyl sheet?  If the former, you might be able to steal a tile from a less visible location and simply fill the ring in and sand/polish smooth.  If the latter, looks like FreeMan has hooked you up.

Comment: it's a vinyl sheet - there is no good way to fill the hole ?

Comment: If just filling without caring how it looks, something like paint should do for 1mm.  If artsy maybe even do a design.  To have it blend in and not stand out, then cutting a section that is more hidden to replace will blend in better.  Just switch the two sections around.